# VBA to select mailbox if an account has multiple mailbox's

Tags: vba, outlook

Here is my requirement.

I have multiple accounts in my OUTLOOK configured.
1) 1@email.com (only one mailbox)
2) 2@email.com (Multiple mailbox's are there. ex: Unix box, Windows Box, Mac box)

Here my 2nd email account has its own mailbox and linked to  multiple mailbox's like UNIX, Windows etc. Each Mailbox has its own inbox and sub folders.

Now i need to select a folder in Unix box (inbox) and run the code to do something in side the folder.

Here's what i have

```
For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
If oaccount ="1@email.com" then
Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' here it selects the inbox folder of account.
For each item in folder.items
Code goes here
next
end if
next
```

This works fine for single mailbox account, but when i do this for multiple mailbox account , it doesn't work.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do the linked mailboxes appear within the profile? Are they simply subfolders of the main mailbox? What's the path of the exact folder you want to select?

Comment: They appear as individual mailbox's. But quiet doesn't show up in accounts tab. ex: 1 account(2@email.com) has 4 mailbox's linked and 4 of them has different accounts, but by just adding 2@email.com in accounts i get to see all 5 mailbox's in outlook not in accounts. You get it?

Comment: Can you loop them using a `For Each` on the `ns.Folders` collection?

Comment: When i loop using for each accounts i get the folders of the source account that we add, not for the linked accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DeliveryStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861633.aspx) property of the `Account` to get its inbox. For example:

```
Dim ns As NameSpace
Set ns = Application.Session

Dim acc As Account
Dim f As Folder

For Each acc In ns.Accounts
    ... Preconditions here ...
    Set f = acc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    ... Now, do some looping ...
Next
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work. Let me give some more information. See my original post, i've added info. Using acc.deliverystore gets me to the accounts inbox and it's folders, but not to linked mailbox's.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on DanL's suggestion to loop through ns.Folders as I cannot tell whether you understood it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub accTopFolder()

Dim oAccount As Account
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim fldr As folder
Dim item As Object
Dim inbx As folder

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

For Each oAccount In Session.Accounts

    Debug.Print vbCr & "oAccount: " & oAccount
    '
    For Each fldr In ns.Folders
    ' Shows all the names so you can replace "test"
        Debug.Print " top folder: " & fldr.name
        If fldr = "test" Then
            Set inbx = fldr.Folders("Inbox")
            'inbx.Display
            For Each item In inbx.Items
                Debug.Print "  item .Subject: " & item.subject
            Next
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

Set inbx = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```