# Retrieve a folder for a specific Outlook account

Tags: c#, office-interop

My application is targetted for Office 2010 and up. I am trying to write a function which processes incoming emails automatically. However, i am finding that the event will only be triggered if the MailItem is received in the default email account. If the user has multiple email accounts added in Outlook, I would like all of them to point to the same event handler if possible.

Here is what i have so far:

```
var inbox = _outlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
items = inbox.Items;

if (inbox != null)
            items.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(OnIncomingEmail);
```

I have tried looping through the _outlookApplication.Session.Accounts object, but couldn't find a method that would let me retrieve the folders for a particular account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953386/vba-to-select-mailbox-if-an-account-has-multiple-mailboxs) which has VBA code to get the folder for each account - it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, loop through the `Namespace.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`. Be prepared to handle errors as some stores (especially if they are not default) might not have all or at least some default folders.