# How to associate another email account to Namespace Object in MS Outlook using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two email addresses in my MS Outlook Account.  I would like to loop through subfolders in my Inbox folder for a specific email account per the code below, but I cannot figure out how to map the variable OutAccount in the below code to the NameSpace.  The code below works, but it's looping through the wrong email account.  How can I perform this relationship, so the loop is performed on the desired NameSpace Account?

```
Dim OutMail As MailItem
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account

Set OutMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'The below code represents the prefered email account I would like to use
Set OutAccount = OutMail.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
 

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For Each acct In myNameSpace.Accounts
    MsgBox acct
Next acct

'But this variable is not accecessing the account referenced above
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)


 
For Each mysubfolder In myFolder.Folders
    MsgBox mysubfolder.Name
Next mysubfolder
```

Comment: The action should be inside the `acct` loop. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953386/vba-to-select-mailbox-if-an-account-has-multiple-mailboxs.

Comment: The `.DeliveryStore` idea [Loop every account using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935522/loop-every-account-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

If the account had been added as a store in Outlook, find the account in the `Namespace.Accounts` collection (don't hardcode the index, use `Account.DisplayName` / `SmtpAddress` properties instead) read the `Account.DelieveryStore` property, then use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` method.