# Loop every account using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to execute a rule in the "Junk Mail" folder of all my Outlook accounts.

I found this on the internet, but it only works on one of the two accounts:

```vb
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim ruleList As String
Dim fldJunk As Outlook.Folder
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account

For Each oAccount In Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts

    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
    ' get rules
    Set myRules = st.GetRules
    ' get Junk e-mail folder
    Set fldJunk = st.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)

    ' iterate all the rules
    For Each rl In myRules
        If rl.Name = "Junk Cleaner" Then
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=fldJunk
            ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
        End If
    Next

Next
```

```
For Each oAccount In Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts
```

Only works on the first of my accounts.

Comment: Suggest adding line `Debug.Print Now, oAccount.DisplayName` following the `For Each ...` to see which account(s) are being picked up in the loop. If not all of them, check if the are are 'Shared'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always processing the same store returned by

```
Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
```

replace that line with

```
Set st = oAccount.DeliveryStore
```